# Windows 10 - Way to change default search mode in Windows Explorer to 'Current folder'

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

Has anyone found a way / hack to set the default search mode in Windows Explorer to 'Current folder'?

[image]

I probably need to search for a folder, by partial name, in the current directory (no recursion) 50+ times a day.

I care about sub-folders maybe once a week.

I know I can use advanced syntax in the search field, but that isn't faster that switching the mode manually.

Comment: My suggestion would be to not use the windows explorer to search.  Use one of MANY MANY free tools (or even the console) to do so.  Which if these tools is best will mostly depend on what you are searching for (txt, doc, ..?).  I myself find the explorer search to be worthless but Microsoft didn't design it for me but the other 99%.

Comment: If you're always searching the same folder (or a manaagable finite set), you can save a search from that folder with the criteria: `kind:folder` and the `Current folder` option selected as well. Then you could open the saved search via a shortcut and search for a partial name within that search...

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Searching the current folder is actually quite fast, hence why we want to set it as the default, making it work like Ctrl+F in Chrome. So this question is very reasonable. I honestly expected more from StackExchange like registry hacks. But in the mean time this works well: https://gist.github.com/Onurtag/166df8b88744c48e93a64b7c89652e0a